# Implementing in C# the same behavior of CTime.GetTime() method

Tags: c#, c++, datetime

I'm trying to implement in C# the behavior of `CTime::GetTime()` method.

Here there is a code snippet of my console application (written in C++/CLI):

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
 int epochYear = 1970;
 int epochMonth = 1;
 int epochDay = 1;

 DateTime managedEpochDate = DateTime(epochYear, epochMonth, epochDay);

 int year = 2013;
 int month = 2;
 int day = 13;
 int hour = 9;
 int minutes = 49;
 int seconds = 46;

 // DateTime/CTime -> Numeric Time (__time64_t)

 DateTime managedDateTime = DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minutes, seconds);
 CTime nativeDateTime = CTime(year, month, day, hour, minutes, seconds);

 DWORD nativeTimeToSerialize = nativeDateTime.GetTime();
 UInt32 managedTimeToSerialize = (managedDateTime - managedEpochDate)
     .TotalSeconds;
}
```

At the end I have the following different values:

- **nativeTimeToSerialize** = 1360745386
- **managedTimeToSerialize** = 1360748986

Can anyone help me to understand the why of this difference?

Comment: The difference is 3600 seconds, or 1 hour. How does that relate to your timezone?

Comment: CTime has functions for declaring whether daylight saving time should be considered - My guess is DateTime does this automatically - hence the hour's difference

Comment: @benjymous actually it's the other way around in this case - see my answer.

Comment: use [`DateTimeOffset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTimeOffset.aspx)

Comment: @Jon: my timezone is +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference comes from the fact that [`CTime` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6989cds%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) you're using converts the time to UTC:

> This constructor makes the appropriate conversion to UTC.

Whereas the [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) contructor (and the [other](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/272ba130%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) one) is timezone unaware in this case:

> The `Kind` property is initialized to `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`.

The [subtraction operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1905yhe2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of `DateTime` also doesn't take timezones into account:

> The `Subtraction(DateTime, DateTime)` method does not consider the value of the `Kind` property of the two `DateTime` values when performing the subtraction.

To get the desired result set the last parameter for the `CTime` constructor appropriately, e.g.:

```
CTime nativeDateTime = CTime(year, month, day, hour, minutes, seconds, 0);
```

For modifying `DateTime` usages instead you need to have:

```
int epochYear = 1970;
int epochMonth = 1;
int epochDay = 1;

DateTime managedEpochDateUtc
    = new DateTime(epochYear, epochMonth, epochDay, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

int year = 2013;
int month = 2;
int day = 13;
int hour = 9;
int minutes = 49;
int seconds = 46;

DateTime managedDateTimeLocal
    = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minutes, seconds, DateTimeKind.Local);

DateTime managedDateTimeUtc = managedDateTimeLocal.ToUniversalTime();

uint managedTimeToSerialize = (uint)(managedDateTimeUtc - managedEpochDateUtc)
 .TotalSeconds;
```

Or, as suggested by [Mgetz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/332733/mgetz) you can use [`DateTimeOffset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTimeOffset.aspx) instead of `DateTime`, which is generally recommended because `DateTime` [doesn't handle timezones very clearly](http://noda-time.blogspot.com/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html).